# Receiving POST data in WCF Service

Tags: wcf, post

I read many tutorials but I could not get this running for my project. I made few GET services which send data and they work great, but I have problems receiving the data. I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me where I fail, instead of posting some links. :)
When I try to call the service in my browser I get the error: Method not allowed. But I Think this is just the first error.

Here is my code.
First the code in Android where I call the service:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String SERVICE_URI = "http://10.0.2.2:51602/RestServiceImpl.svc";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URI + "/registerUser");
    request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    try {
        JSONStringer user = new JSONStringer()
                .object()
                .key("userInfo")
                .object()
                    .key("Email").value("mail")
                    .key("Password").value("pass")
                    .key("Cauntry").value("country")
                    .key("UserName").value("username")
                .endObject()
        .endObject();

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(user.toString());
        request.setEntity(entity);

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

IRestServiceImpl.cs:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestServiceImpl
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "registerUser",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void receiveData(String data);
}
```

RestServiceImpl.cs:

```
public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
{
    public void receiveData(String data)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">

        <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web">

        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're passing a JSON **object** to the operation, but the operation is expecting a JSON **string**. If I understand correctly the Java code, this is what you're sending:

```
{
    "userInfo" : {
        "Email" : "mail",
        "Password" : "pass",
        "Cauntry" : "country",
        "UserName" : "username"
    }
}
```

Which is not a JSON string.

There are a couple of things you can do. The first alternative is to modify the operation not to take a string, but to take a data contract which is equivalent to that object.

The code would look something like the one below. Notice that you should also change the body format to `Bare` (instead of `Wrapped`).

```
public class RequestData
{
    public UserInfo userInfo { get; set; }
}

public class UserInfo
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Cauntry { get; set; } // typo to match the OP
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestServiceImpl
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "registerUser",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void receiveData(RequestData data);
}
```

Another alternative, if the "schema" of the data changes every time, would be to take the input as a *Stream* (not a String). That way you should be able to accept basically any input. You may also need a content type mapper. You can find more information about this scenario at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx.

Comment: OK, I changed it to bare and wrote a data contract. But when I send the JSON object in my android emulator, nothing happens. I added a breakpoint inside the receiveData method.

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happens"? What do you get on the `HttpResponse` instance you received when making the call?

Comment: Nothing because before I can get a response, I get ConnectTimeoutException.

Comment: One thing you can try to do is to [enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) at the server to see if there is any exception which could explain the problem.