# Capture Json Data in C# sent from Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, json, wcf

I have been trying to post json data from an html page using the following code:

```
$scope.SubmitForm = function() {
var review = new Review($scope.reviewList);
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(review);
console.log(jsonData);
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "Services/CafeReview.svc/DoWork",
    data: review,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d);
    }

});
}
}
```

The console does list down the data : 
{"reviewListArray":[{"item":"s","rating":{"label":"2","value":2},"suggestion":"Good"},{"item":"cvbcvb","rating":{"label":"4","value":4},"suggestion":"bad"},{"item":"sdfvsdvsd","rating":{"label":"4","value":4},"suggestion":"ugly"}]}

However, what gets posted is d: null.

The method DoWork() is the one that is provided by default when we add an ajax enabled wcf service.

```
 [OperationContract]
        public void DoWork()
        {
            // Add your operation implementation here
            return;
        }
```

How do I retrieve this data on the server side? I have been stuck for a long time now. The first problem is obviously that d:null is being posted

Comment: [OperationContract]        public void DoWork(string data)//maybe string data or else..
        {
            // Add your operation implementation here
            return;
        }

Comment: Does not work . If I add any parameter to the DoWork() method it leads to an internal server error in the networks tab

Comment: Read this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828716/receiving-post-data-in-wcf-service

Answer (score 0):

you need to create class like following

```
  [DataContract]
  public class reviewList
  {
     [DataMember]
   public List<Review> reviewListArray{ get; set; }
  }

 [DataContract]
 public class Review
 {
   [DataMember]
   public string item { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string suggestion { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public List<Ratting> rating{ get; set; }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class Ratting
  {
   [DataMember]
   public int label{ get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public int value{ get; set; }
  }
```

Now use this class in your method

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Review")]
    public void DoWork(reviewList data)
    {
        // Add your operation implementation here
    }
```